# Command line compilation of Hello World in Eiffel (Unknown root class error)

Tags: command-line, eiffel

I'm trying to build a hello world program in Eiffel, and this is how I tried. I use Mac OS X 10.10.

1. I installed the Eiffel programming language with `brew install eiffelstudio`. Everything works fine without an issue. I have all the tools in `/usr/local/Cellar/eiffelstudio/14.05`
2. I came up with an example code from this site: https://dev.eiffel.com/Compiling_Hello_World

This is the code.

```
class
    ROOT_CLASS
create
    make
feature -- Initialization 
    make
        -- Creation procedure.
        do
            io.put_string ("Hello World!")
        end   
end
```

I'm trying to build this code into a binary that can be executed.

I tried `ec hello.e` to  get this error message.

```
Configuration error: Unknown root class.
What to do: Make sure that the name given in the Ace for the root
  class corresponds to a class of the universe. (If more than
  one, specify the cluster, see example in ETL D.2, page 514.)
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the file and the name of the class should be the same, so the error should disappear if you either rename the file to `root_class.e` or change the class name to read `HELLO`.

Comment: I got root_class binary and root_class.ecf, then how to execute the binary? Thanks.

Comment: @prosseek, the executable is located in `EIFGENs/root_class/W_code` with the name `root_class`. Normally you use a command-line shell to run it.